# Can I use LoRa and Prompt Tuning at the same time for text summarization with GPT?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, summarization, huggingface

LoRA is to insert and learn the rank composition matrix created by dimensionally reducing the weight matrix in the transformer. Prompt Tuning, on the other hand, typically uses a soft prompt that encodes the prompt within the model to learn, rather than a hard prompt that a person gives the task directly. Both are effective in lightening, especially prompt tuning, which is better than hard prompt use.

Both techniques can also be implemented using the peft module.

```
from peft import get_peft_model, PeftModel, TaskType, LoraConfig, PromptTuningConfig, PromptTuningInit

for path,dirs,files in os.walk('/root/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--kakaobrain--kogpt'):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith('tokenizer.json'):
      tokenizer_path = path
print(tokenizer_path)

prompt_config = PromptTuningConfig(
    task_type=TaskType.CAUSAL_LM,
    num_virtual_tokens=10,
    prompt_tuning_init=PromptTuningInit.TEXT,
    prompt_tuning_init_text="Read the following and summarize:",
    tokenizer_name_or_path=tokenizer_path
)

lora_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type = TaskType.CAUSAL_LM,
    r=8, lora_alpha=32, lora_dropout=0.1,
    target_modules = ['q_proj', 'v_proj'],
    # target_modules = r".*(q_proj|v_proj)",
)
```

However, the get_feft_model function receives only the model and one peft_config as parameters.

```
peft_model = get_peft_model(base_model, prompt_config)
```

I want to use both techniques at the same time. How shall I do it?